# UICollection View ios 7 issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

i am using this Code for my UIcollectionView , its working fine in iOS6 but with ios7 and its not working , as once i start scrolling the CollectionView the entire elements Orientation messed up.
Any idea to this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.filteredNewsItems.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NewsItemCell *cell = (NewsItemCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

[cell loadWithArticle:self.filteredNewsItems[indexPath.item]];

return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: there you go snapshot added.

Comment: also this only happens after scroll , otherwise its looks fine and oriented.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
 static NSString *cellIdenfier = @"collectionCell"; // this can be any string
NewsItemCell *cell = (NewsItemCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdenfier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

your cell got messed up because while scrolling cell is re used so as in your case providing static cell identifier can fix your problem.
if problem still persist with you then let me know

Comment: Well i am doing the Same static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"NewsItemCell"; , so its not working with ios7

Comment: so where you are defining your identifier string? and also put a break point and print are you getting the right value

Comment: its Globally Define in the top of the File .

Comment: have you tried to print your identifier in cell for row at index ? are you getting the right value?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your loadWithArticle: method is always adding views to the NewsItemCell rather than reusing any existing subviews that you created the first time the cell was populated. Can you  provide the code for loadWithArticle:?